# How can I generate a null type in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, nullpointerexception, null, quadtree

I need to make a Quadtree in Haskell. But I never used the language before. As I understand, there is no null pointers in Haskell. So how could I instantiate a null version of Group for the pointers of the Quadtree(if there is even a way)?

```
data Group = Group {
    idf :: Int,
    name :: String,
    lat :: Int,
    long :: Int,
    nw :: Group,
    ne :: Group,
    sw :: Group,
    se :: Group
} deriving Show

main :: IO()

main = do
    let g1 = Group { idf = 0, name = "Ababa", lat = 32, long = 40, nw = ???}
    print g1
```

I know Maybe exists. No idea how to use it in this context though.

Comment: Does `Group` represent a location and its neighbors, or subdivisions of a single location? That might affect which use of `Maybe` suggested in the two answers I would use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use `Maybe`. It's a type that can have values of two different kinds: either `Nothing` or `Just x` where `x` is a value of some other type.

```
data Group = Group {
    ...
    nw :: Maybe Group,
    ne :: Maybe Group,
    sw :: Maybe Group,
    se :: Maybe Group
} deriving Show

main = do
    let g1 = Group { ..., nw = Nothing, ne = Nothing, sw = Nothing, se = Nothing }
    print g1

    ...

    let g2 = Group { ... ne = Just g1, ... }
```

Answer (score 2):

I would add a constructor to your `Group`.

```
data Group = Empty | Group {
    idf :: Int,
    name :: String,
    lat :: Int,
    long :: Int,
    nw :: Group,
    ne :: Group,
    sw :: Group,
    se :: Group
    } deriving Show
```

Usually it's a bad sign if you're using record syntax in a type with multiple constructors, so you may want to educate yourself on the pitfalls.